# Slow Operating System

Tags: google-chrome, memory, linux-mint, operating-systems, memory-management

I am using Linux Mint. My system info is like below.

[image]

When I tried to open more tabs in Google Chrome browser, I found my Operating System become slow. How can I get rid of the situation?

Memory status is like below

[image]

Screen shot of `top` command

[image]

Comment: Are you running any other programs or services in the background? You're using so much memory that you're now activating swap storage. Swap becomes active when you run out of memory which then consumes CPU% and Disk I/O% so you will notice a slow down.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherJohnson. I run nothing but Google Chrome Browser.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot with running processes ? Open a terminal and type : `top`

Comment: You are showing you are using almost 2GB of swap which is ALOT.  Using swap will slow ANY computer to a CRAWL.  You have to figure out what is using so much memory and either fix it (memory leak) or stop it (kill uneeded processes).

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume. I added screen shot of `top` command. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your hard drive is swapping very heavily.   You can probably greatly improve things by tuning how the system uses swap.  Most versions of Linux (I know Ubuntu and CentOS - so I assume Mint as well) set the default value of vm.swappiness to 60.  Decreasing this to 10 can make the world of difference.

To do this add the line "vm.swappiness = 10" to the end of /etc/sysctl.conf (you will need to be root to do this), then (again as root), run the command "sysctl -p" to immediately enable this - or reboot.

You may also need to clear out your browser cache in case its corrupted.